# why does my loop only run once?

Tags: java, loops

This is my code

```
executeProgram:
    for (int i= 0; 1< memory.length; i++)
    {   
        String twoDigitMemory = String.format("%02d",memory[i] );
        System.out.print(twoDigitMemory +" ? +");
        accumulator = input.nextInt();

        if (input.nextInt() == -99999)
        {
            System.out.println("*** Program loading completed ***");
            System.out.println("*** Program execution begins  ***");
            break executeProgram;
        }
    }
```

This is my output. I enter 123.

```
***            Welcome to Simpletron!            ***
*** Please enter your program one instruction    ***
*** (or data word) at a time. I will display     ***
*** the location number and a question mark (?)  ***
*** You then type the word for that location.    ***
*** Type -99999 to stop entering your program    ***
00 ? +123
```

after entering 123 and pressing enter I expect the for loop to run again
printing "00 ? +" but nothing happens, the input does get saved to the variable

Comment: Do you actually mean to write `1 < memory.length` or `i < memory.length`!!!!

Comment: Your if should be `if (accumulator  == -99999)`?

Comment: you have a typo. I suspect your for loop should be:  `for (int i= 0; i< memory.length; i++)` not `1<memory.length`?

Comment: yes it sahould be i not 1 but it makes no difference it still performs the same

Comment: So show the declaration and any assignments to your `memory`, please.

Comment: but changing the if statement to accumulator fixed the problem thanks @SMA

Comment: @SMA if you write your comment as an answer I will mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Why are you breaking to a label before the start of the loop?

Comment: I want to loop through an array and add user input unless the user inputs -99999 the it exits the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting user to input number twice. Once you are storing in accumulater while the other just to compare the number like `if (input.nextInt() == -99999)` which is not needed. Instead you should use `accumulater` variable for checking like:

```
if (accumulater == -99999)
```